# WPF RichTextBox Limit to single line possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am having an exotic question.
I use a RichTextBox as some sort of Adressbar. It basically looks like this

```
        <RichTextBox  Loaded="adressBarFormat" LostFocus="adressBarFormat" GotFocus="adressBarFocused" Height="19" Margin="82,14,137,0" Name="adressBar" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" IsDocumentEnabled="True" Foreground="#FFABABAC" Style="{DynamicResource adressBar}" AcceptsReturn="False" MinWidth="35" >
            <FlowDocument Name="flw" PageWidth="1000">
                <Paragraph Name="FullAdress">
                    <Run>C:\Test\Testapp\Meintest</Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Whenever the textbox is not focused the adressBarFormat kicks in and replaces the "\" with two spaces and marks the last entry after that in a different color and whenever I focus it again it switches back to "\" and is uniformly colored. That works pretty well. Also the flow document and the used height makes sure that the bar always appears to be single lined. Now within the function I simply do this to read the string I need:

```
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(adressBar.Document.ContentStart,adressBar.Document.ContentEnd);
        string richText = textRange.Text;
```

I also make sure I clear everything in my box like this before I add my new Stuff in there:

```
flw.Blocks.Clear();            
FullAdress.Inlines.Clear();
adressBar.Document.Blocks.Clear();
```

Then I do some regex to find if there is a backspace, if there is one, the string gets split into substrings representing the folders. They all get saved as a Hyperlinkobect, which on click call another function.
When I finished conversion and sytling I do this to get it in my box again.:

```
FullAdress.Inlines.Add(link); //happens multiple times with different links
adressBar.Document.Blocks.Add(FullAdress);
```

Now something crazy happens: There is an automatic newline placed in my box. I can use the arrow key do navigate down to it. These add up whenever I call the function again. I first thought that there was a newline in the richtText string but there is none.
So my question is: Is there any way to prevent that a new line gets added?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using RemoveAt(0) (with appropriate checks) instead of using Clear(). This will ensure that you you don't have any stray nulls in your collections.